# Make positioned divs take up all space until next element on axis

Tags: css

I have a couple of divs which all have a `left: XX%;` property.
I want to to take of the full width **until the next div**.

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="left: 0%; height: 10px; background: red;">

  </div>
  <div style="left: 30%; height: 10px; background: green;">

  </div>
  <div style="left: 50%; height: 10px; background: blue;">

  </div>
  <div style="left: 70%; height: 10px; background: orange;">

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve, that the child divs take up all the space in the row up until the next div? So in the example, there should be a single row with 30% red, 20% green, 20% blue and 30% orange.
I don't know the percentages or the number of childs beforehand.

[image]

Comment: try display inline-block with width percentage.

Comment: You can use flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Can you also post screenshot for expected output?

Comment: Positioned - _how_? Relative, absolute? _“How can I achieve, that the child divs take up all the space in the row up until the next div?”_ - that is rather not a thing you should be using positioning for in the first place.

Comment: @misorude Let me rephrase: How can I make sure each div takes up 100% of the width from its starting point (indicated by `left`) up until the next divs starting point?

Comment: Relative positioning only moves an element in relation to the position it would normally have, that has no influence on the elements dimensions. And absolute positioning takes an element out of the layout flow - it doesn’t know anything about the position or dimensions of any of its siblings any more, and vice versa. The _only_ thing that would work here, is absolute positioning, and specifying not only `left`, but `right` as well - then the element’s own width can be determined based on those two “coordinates”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easiest way is to use `flex-box` in parent's class and `flex-grow` in children's classes.

I hope below solution is what you expect to achieve. If not - please add result you expect to have.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.red,
.orange {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.green,
.blue {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="red">

  </div>
  <div class="green">

  </div>
  <div class="blue">

  </div>
  <div class="orange">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however I was hoping to not have to set `flex-grow` manually on the childs, as I don't know the percentages or the number of childs beforehand.

Comment: so how do you want to indicate which on should be larger and which one should be smaller?

Comment: Well each of the divs has a `left: x%` property, as mentioned. But I solved it now using absolute positioning and right as well as in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Float:left` for each color bar and then using javascript get the starting of next color bar and adjust its width accordingly.

```js
function adjust() {
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("color")
            for (var i = 0; i < divs.length - 1; i++) {
                var width1 = divs[i].style.left.slice(0, -1);
                var width2 = divs[i + 1].style.left.slice(0, -1);
                var diff = width2 - width1;
                divs[i].style.width = diff + "%";
            }
            divs[divs.length - 1].style.width = (100 - divs[divs.length - 1].style.left.slice(0, -1) + "%")
            //To adjust width of last color bar
        }
```

```css
.row {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="adjust()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="color" style="left: 0%; height: 10px; background: red;float: left;">

        </div>
        <div class="color" style="left: 30%; height: 10px; background: green;float: left;">

        </div>
        <div class="color" style="left: 50%; height: 10px; background: blue;float: left;">

        </div>
        <div class="color" style="left: 70%; height: 10px; background: orange;float: left;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```